# How to use the Comparable CompareTo on Strings in Java

Tags: java, comparable, compareto

I can use it to sort by emp id but I'm not sure if it is possible to compare strings. I get an error the operator is undefined for strings.

```
public int compareTo(Emp i) {
            if (this.getName() == ((Emp ) i).getName())
                return 0;
            else if ((this.getName()) > ((Emp ) i).getName())
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;
```

Comment: Curious, why do you need to cast `i` to `Emp` when you've already declared it to be `Emp` in the method signature?

Answer (score 51):

What you need to use is the `compareTo()` method of Strings.

```
return this.getName().compareTo(i.getName());
```

That should do what you want.

Usually when implementing the `Comparable` interface, you will just combine the results of using other `Comparable` members of the class.

Below is a pretty typical implementation of a `compareTo()` method:

```
class Car implements Comparable<Car> {
    int year;
    String make, model;
    public int compareTo(Car other) {
        if (!this.make.equalsIgnoreCase(other.make))
            return this.make.compareTo(other.make);
        if (!this.model.equalsIgnoreCase(other.model))
            return this.model.compareTo(other.model);
        return this.year - other.year;
    }
}
```

Comment: when i replace  "else if ((this.getName()) > ((Emp ) i).getName())" with "else if (this.getName().compareTo(((Emp ) i).getName() > 0)", I get a similar error saying operator > is undefine for type String,int

Comment: @Jack: That's because your `> 0` is inside of the call to `compareTo()`; it needs to be outside that last parenthesis to compare the return value of the string comparison against zero (and then you need another parenthesis to complete the `else if` condition).

Comment: @Jack, you should probably use the version of the method that everyone else is suggesting.  Just directly return the value of `string.compareTo(string)`.

Answer (score 10):

Pretty sure your code can just be written like this:

```
public int compareTo(Emp other)
{
    return this.getName().compareTo(other.getName());
}
```

Comment: Oh I see. I must have been confused switching from comparing ints and string and used > sign. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

Java [String](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) already implements Comparable. So you could simply write your method as

```
public int compareTo(Emp emp) {
   return this.getName().compareTo(emp.getName());
}
```

(ofcourse make sure you add proper validations such as null checks etc)

Also in your code, do not try to compare Strings using '=='. Use 'equals' method instead. '==' only compare string references while [equals](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) semantically compares two strings.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to cast i to Emp, it's already an Emp:

```
public int compareTo(Emp i) {
    return getName().compareTo(i.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't

`if (this.getName() == ((Emp ) i).getName())`

be

`if (this.getName().equals(i.getName()))`

Comment: As indicated by others, `getName().compareTo(i.getName());` is a better option anyway.